# A geodesic on a unit sphere

Tags: vectors, spherical-coordinates, spheres, geodesic, spherical-geometry

Points $A(\cos\alpha,0,\sin\alpha)$ and $B(0,\cos\beta,\sin\beta)$, $(0<\alpha$ and $\beta<\pi/2)$ are on a unit sphere and $l$ is the shortest line (geodesic) between $A$ and $B$ on the sphere. And $C$ is a point on $l$ with maximal $z$ coordinate. If $H$ is the foot of the orthogonal projection of $C$ onto the $xy$-plane and if the angle between the positive $x$-axis and line $OH$ is $\gamma$ then find $\tan(\gamma)$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Can someone point out to me how to tackle this problem? I tried to refer books on geodesics but most of them are based on high-level mathematics. A hint on how to solve the problem or a reference to a book containing similar problems will really be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to copy the sentence defining $C$. This problem is pure elementary geometry and a bit of vector algebra.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: When tackling problems like that, you need to "grok" the geometry.  In this case, A is a point on the XZ-plane, on circular arc, at angle α above the Z=0 plane.  B is a point on the YZ-plane, on circular arc, at angle β above the Z=0 plane. The "great circle" between A and B is in the plane ABO, so maximal z is the largest value of Z attained on the arc AB (hint: arc is not in horizontal plane).  The point along AB, where the tangent becomes horizontal (tangent vector with z-component == 0) will be the point of highest "rise" along the geodesic.  Look for dz/d=0 along the circle AB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

The shortest curve $l$ connecting $A$ with $B$ is on a great circle $\gamma$ through $A$ and $B$. This great circle lies in a plane  through $O$. This plane is spanned by the given vectors $a=(\cos\alpha,0,\sin\alpha)$ and $b=(0,\cos\beta,\sin\beta)$. The plane intersects the $(x,y)$-plane in a line $g$, and the great circle $\gamma$ intersects the $(x,y)$-plane in two points of $g$. The direction of this line indicates where the $z$-highest point $C$ of $\gamma$ lies, and therefore the direction in which the point $H$ lies.

**Make a figure!**

Comment: I can see that the points A and B are on the xz and yz planes. And since the plane containing the great circle is spanned by the vectors OA and OB, does it not mean that the plane itself passes through the origin? And what does a maximal z coordinate mean geometrically in this case?